# A detail in the proof of Jordan's theorem

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The (usual) proof with homology first inductively shows that complements of embedded disks are acyclic. In doing so, Mayer-Vietoris is applied, and this assumes that their complements in the sphere are open.

Is this a triviality? The geometry of the embeddings can be non-trivial, so I doubt that a CW-structure/deformation retraction is so obvious (for Hatcher, Rotman etc.) that they don't even mention it. Note that the image of an embedding is not necessarily closed/open.

Even worse, this fact is used by Hatcher to prove invariance of domain itself! Can someone illuminate for me this problem leading to a (seemingly) circular reasoning?

Comment: Hatcher has a proof that $\tilde H_i(S^n-h[D^k])=0$ for all embeddings $h:D^k\hookrightarrow S^n$ of balls into spheres and all $i\ge 0$. Note that $h$ must be a closed map since $D^k$ is compact and $S^n$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: Aren't the embedded disks compact? In Hatcher for example, $D^k$ is the closed unit disk, so it's compact, and its image is therefore compact in $S^n$ and thus closed. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @Hamcke: Yes, my question is about exactly this proof. So, answer it.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: You are right. I didn't even think about the properties of $S^n$ there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hatcher has a proof that $\tilde H_i(S^n-h[D^k])=0$ for all embeddings $h:D^k\hookrightarrow S^n$ of balls into spheres and all $i\ge 0$. It can be found in chapter $2.B$ of his book *Algebraic Topology*. Note that $h$ must be a closed map since $D^k$ is compact and $S^n$ is Hausdorff. Hence $h[D^k]$ is closed and we can apply Mayer-Vietoris to the cover $A=S^n-h[D_-^k]$, $B=S^n-h[D_+^k]$